# Git Error -4058 while trying to npm install nw-builder

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code, npm, nwjs

I just created a new folder on my Desktop and loaded it to VSCode so I can start building/learning about **NW.js**. The first thing I've done was to open VSCode Terminal and execute `npm init -y`, then I've proceeded to run `npm install nw@sdk`. No error whatsoever.

Now my new folder has a `package.json`, a `package-lock.json`, and `node_modules` folder.

`package.json` content:

```
{
  "name": "rename-merra-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.62.1-sdk"
  }
}
```

When I try to run `npm install nw-builder --save-dev` as the reference suggests @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/nw-builder, I got the following **error**:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Misharin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-23T03_41_13_504Z-debug-0.log
```

[image: Error 4058 after npm install nw-builder --save-dev]

The **.log file** can be found here: https://pastebin.com/cZAmugRF

**I've tried the following**:

- Restart VSCode
- Restart My Computer
- Run `npm install` (Up to date, 120 packages, version 8.5.5)
- Run `npm` outside VSCode, directly on the prompt (same error)
- Delete package-lock.json
- Reinstall NodeJS (17.8.0)
- Install an older version of NodeJS (17.7.1)
- Search for node.js running in the background (there is none)
- Disable Windows Security
- Run `npm cache clear --force`

**Does anyone have any idea how to solve this error?**

Maybe one of the git links (https://registry.npmjs.org/nw-builder) from the nw-builder package is down/offline? In that case, is there any way around it so I can start building with nw.js?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It looks like you never installed Git, or if you did, you never set up your PATH to let npm *run* the installed Git.

Comment: That was it, @torek! Thank you for your time! You rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Git installed:

- https://git-scm.com

You'll likely want to change your code to:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "0.62.1-sdk"
  }
```

The `^` can download the normal version if it was published after the `sdk` version.

I haven't used `nw-builder`, but from my understanding, it hasn't received any updates in several years. There is a GitHub issue related to this:

- https://github.com/nwjs-community/nw-builder/issues/530

Finally, here are instructions for how to manually create your own build:

- https://gitlab.com/TheJaredWilcurt/battery-app-workshop

More tutorials are at:

- https://nwutils.io

Comment: That was it! Yesterday I've given up and went on installing Electron and got the git error more explicitly, so I've noticed it was the problem all along. I've installed it and set it up on my PATH and now I can install the package with no problem. Thank you!